# How to settle "aligned in tsfile but not aligned in IoTDB" error in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

> ERROR o.a.i.d.q.e.PlanExecutor:1329 · fail to load file 1658465460360-0-0-0.tsfile exception.query.QueryProcessException: root.ads_joOJKIUBLUNro3Wl2Ue signal is aligned in the loading TsFile but is not aligned in IoTDB.

I found the error information of Apache IoTDB I used very confusing: ERROR o.a.i.d.q.e.PlanExecutor:1329 · fail to load file 1658465460360-0-0-0.tsfile exception.query.QueryProcessException: root.ads_joOJKIUBLUNro3Wl2Ue signal is aligned in the loading TsFile but is not aligned in IoTDB. Anyone understand this error information and suggest me how to settle this problem?

How to deal this question?

Answer (score 0):

It appears like the time series needs to be set aligned when created in Apache IoTDB. You can create the aligned time series first and then load them to see if this error has been solved.